# How to set custom float values to y-axis in an MPAndroidChart PieChart

Tags: android, pie-chart, mpandroidchart

In my application I want to show float data (from JSON) to a y-axis in a pie chart. It is taking the values but converting into percentage values. It not showing my data, it is showing percentage values. How do I show floats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment these lines:

```
mChart.setUsePercentValues(false);
mChart.highlightValues(null);

dataSet.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter());
```

Comment: Thank you nabil. It solved my issue. Thank you very much.